# feathersjs sequelize call stored procedure by hook doesn't resolve

Tags: stored-procedures, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I have a problem creating a hook calling a stored procedure.

My custom service hooks (customservice.hooks.js) are :

```
const callstored = require('../../hooks/callstored')
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [callstored()],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
 ...
```

My service class (customservice.class.js):

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

class Service {
  constructor (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  find (params) {
    return Promise.resolve( [] );
  }

  get (id, params) {
    return Promise.resolve({

      id, text: `A new message with ID: ${id}!`
    });
  }

  create (data, params) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current)));
    }

    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }

  update (id, data, params) {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }

  patch (id, data, params) {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }

  remove (id, params) {
    return Promise.resolve({ id });
  }
}

module.exports = function (options) {
  return new Service(options);
};

module.exports.Service = Service;
```

And my service (customservice.service.js) :

```
const createService = require('./rankingvotes.class.js');
const hooks = require('./rankingvotes.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {

  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'rankingvotes',
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/rankingvotes', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('rankingvotes');

  service.hooks(hooks);

  app.publish(() => {

  });
};
```

And finally my hook is (callstored.js)

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function () {
  return function (hook) {
    sequelize = hook.app.get('sequelizeClient');
    let result=[];
    return sequelize.query('CALL RANKING();',{
      nest: true,
      raw: true }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response[0]) //data are correct
        hook.data=response[0]; 
        return hook;
      }).error(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        return hook;
      });
  }
}
```

If I check the console I got data correctly, but nothing calling from a REST client like Postman.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the response you have to set [hook.result](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#contextresult).

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function () {
  return async hook => {
    try {
      const sequelize = hook.app.get('sequelizeClient');
      const response = await sequelize.query('CALL RANKING();',{
        nest: true,
        raw: true
      });

      console.log(response[0]) //data are correct
      context.result = response[0]; 
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    return hook;
  }
}
```

[hook.data](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#contextdata) is the request data and is only available for `create`, `update` and `patch`.

Keep in mind that setting `hook.result` will *skip* your custom service `find` if it is set in a `before` hook.